# How to combine multiple double range query in lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

I have several fields of 8-dimensional DoublePoint for each document.
I want to query a few DoublePoint fields together (like an AND operator).
using [newRangeQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/DoublePoint.html#newRangeQuery-java.lang.String-double:A-double:A-) 
which I'm not sure exactly how to use of itself.

First, how exactly do I use the newRangeQuery? (I didn't find any proper examples).
Second, how do I combine several queries like that?

Update:
8-dimensional DoublePoint would look like:
[1.2, 1.3, 2.3, 3.4, 1.2, 1.3, 2.3, 3.4]

And what I mean by example is exactly how to use the newRangeQuery inside a searcher full code/use.
How would I create a searcher without analyzer? or without the score function? (Since the score is for text isn't it?)
 ([simple full searcher example from here](https://www.baeldung.com/lucene-file-search))

```
public List<Document> searchFiles(String inField, String queryString) {
   Query query = new QueryParser(inField, analyzer)
      .parse(queryString);
   Directory indexDirectory = FSDirectory
      .open(Paths.get(indexPath));
   IndexReader indexReader = DirectoryReader
      .open(indexDirectory);
   IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
   TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(query, 10);

   return topDocs.scoreDocs.stream()
     .map(scoreDoc -> searcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Use BooleanQuery to combine queries.

Comment: What exactly is 8-dimensional DoublePoint? Could you please show us an example (2 or 3 dimensional would be enough)?

Comment: I looked at the JavaDoc. For me it looks like the DoublePoint is the representation for multi-double values field. Then, newRangeQuery would take field name and range for each of the double values...what exactly on that is not understood?